# How to add different colors to different letters in a word in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

How can i add specfic color to each letter in a word , the color of each letter should be same if it is repeating. Like if b is repeating then all b letters should have the same color.

Here is my color obj as key value pair-

```
const colorObj = 
{
  a: "red",
  b: "green",
  c: "blue",
  d: "violet",
  e: "yellow",
  f: "orange",
  g: "brown",
  h: "indigo",
  i: "cadetblue",
  j: "chocolate",
  k: "crimson",
  l: "darkcyan",
  m: "darkgrey",
  n: "darkolivegreen",
  o: "darkorange",
  p: "darkviolet",
  q: "deeppink",
  r: "fuchsia",
  s: "gold",
  t: "greenyellow",
  u: "khaki",
  v: "springgreen",
  w: "yellowgreen",
  x: "sienna",
  y: "royalblue",
  z: "peachpuff",
},
```

Here curState is the string , for eg curState = "hello"
i tried to create an array of objects -

```
  let arr = [];
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(arr);

  for (let i = 0; i < curState.length; i++) {
    arr.push({
      id: i,
      letter: curState[i],
      color: colorObj [curState[i]],
      isPressed: false,
    });
  }
```

i was rendering the final array in a card component like this -

```
<div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <div className="my-grid">
          {cards.map((item) => (
            <Cards
              color={item.color}
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              text={item.letter}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

here is the card compoent-

```
import React from "react";
import { BsTrashFill } from "react-icons/bs";
function Cards(props) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}
      onClick={props.handleClick}
      className="h-20 w-20 text-yellow-100 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer relative rounded-xl"
    >
      {props.text}
      <span onClick={props.delete} className=" absolute top-2 right-2">
        <BsTrashFill />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
Cards.defaultProps = {
  // color: "blue",
};
export default Cards;
```

note the color prop is set to as the style for the card component.
but for some reason it dosen't seem to work.

Comment: Can you add the code for `card` component

Comment: Hey i added the card component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work When I tried the code in sandbox, it does render properly.

One issue that I can think of is that in your code, where you loop through the string, once you finish the loop, you need to set the `cards` value to the `array` returned.

But again, I cannot be sure about that since you have not included the complete code. But here's the solution that I used. Maybe you can compare the code and then fix it.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { BsTrashFill } from "react-icons/bs";

const colorObj = 
{
  a: "red",
  b: "green",
  c: "blue",
  d: "violet",
  e: "yellow",
  f: "orange",
  g: "brown",
  h: "indigo",
  i: "cadetblue",
  j: "chocolate",
  k: "crimson",
  l: "darkcyan",
  m: "darkgrey",
  n: "darkolivegreen",
  o: "darkorange",
  p: "darkviolet",
  q: "deeppink",
  r: "fuchsia",
  s: "gold",
  t: "greenyellow",
  u: "khaki",
  v: "springgreen",
  w: "yellowgreen",
  x: "sienna",
  y: "royalblue",
  z: "peachpuff",
};


function Cards(props) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}
      onClick={props.handleClick}
      className="h-20 w-20 text-yellow-100 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer relative rounded-xl"
    >
      {props.text}
      <span onClick={props.delete} className=" absolute top-2 right-2">
        <BsTrashFill />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}



export default function App() {

  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    const curState = 'It workssz';

  for (let i = 0; i < curState.length; i++) {
    arr.push({
      id: i,
      letter: curState[i],
      color: colorObj [curState[i]],
      isPressed: false,
    });
  }
  setCards(arr);
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <div className="my-grid">
          {cards.map((item) => (
            <Cards
              color={item.color}
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              text={item.letter}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export { Cards };
```

Here's the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-yalow-z3swte)

Comment: Ah thanks it did work. It was a silly mistake from my side. By the way Can you please tell me why you used useEffect()  ?

Comment: No problem. Well, I'm guessing you might be receiving the text from some other component or from some input. In that case, if the text ever changes, you'll need to re-render the cards component with the latest word and hence useEffect(ofc you have to add the string var as dependency array ).